# BAPI_PPMSRVAPS_SAVEMULTI_30A runs without errors, but values are not updated

Tags: abap, bapi, sap-apo

I am using the BAPI `BAPI_PPMSRVAPS_SAVEMULTI_30A` and after hitting this FM, there are no returned errors, but the MODES are not updated. Other tables that needs to be updated were updated, it is just the MODES that was not.

**EDIT:** After more observations, I think, the BAPI is not the problem. The database `/SAPAPO/MODE` is even updated. Here the issue in `/SAPAPO/SCC03`, the fix duration becomes zero whenever we run our custom program. It is weird because, it is reflecting zero in `/SAPAPO/SCC03` only when the fix duration is manually updated or perhaps, modified by other enhancement. When PPM is created initially with the custom program, fix duration is good and reflecting the correct value in the `/SAPAPO/SCC03`.

I am thinking that there might be flagging that once ppm is altered manually or by any enhancement or by CIF or etc, then the fix duration's display will remain as zero, even though it updated the fix duration value in the database. Do you know spot which I could check regarding this related issue?

Comment: Without any information on the code and use case, it's hard to help.

Comment: @vwegert please my edit for more details. Thanks for any help.